# Bootstrap Wizard not working with custom style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use custom style for tabClass and my progressbar and validator stop working:

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({'tabClass': 'bwizard-steps'}, {
                    onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {

                        var $valid = $("#installForm").valid();
                        if(!$valid) {
                            return false;
                        }

                    }, onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                        var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                        var $current = index+1;
                        var $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
                        $('#rootwizard .progress-bar').css({width:$percent+'%'});
                    }, onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                        return false;   
                    }
    });
```

How can I fix this?